Which are the most consulted Reformed theology dictionaries?
I would like to expand my theological library, but I don't have a strong background in Reformed theology. Which theological term dictionaries are most commonly used in academia?
Thanks in advance.

I'm not too sure why, but in Christian publishing what we'd normally think of as dictionaries are often called "lexicons", while the books with "dictionary" on the title are functionally encyclopedias. As it's not clear in the question which you are after I'll give a few of both. Additionally, while these resources are used in academia in the sense that Bible college and seminary students would consult them, in theological research you're only likely to find the lexicons actually being used (just as in other fields you wouldn't see encyclopedias cited in journals.)
Biblical studies
For the Biblical languages, the dominant lexicons are BDAG for Greek, and BDB or HALOT for Hebrew.
There are lots of "dictionaries" (ie, encyclopedias) for Biblical studies. The most detailed would be the TDOT & TDNT. While you can get these in paper, I think it's 25 volumes in total, so most people now use digital versions, such as from Accordance or Logos. There are abridged one volume editions which would make more sense to get in paper.
Note that these resources are not specifically Reformed, and many of the editors held personally to beliefs which would not at all fit within evangelicalism or Reformed Christianity. But they are respected as world-class resources, and so are used by Reformed students and scholars.
There are also more specifically Reformed resources. For example, the one volume New Bible Dictionary from IVP is well respected. The eight volume IVP Bible Dictionary series can obviously get into more detail. But as these still focus on the Biblical texts, you won't find all the theological terms there. For example, the New Bible Dictionary has an article on "salvation", but not "soteriology".
Systematic Theology
To be honest, from my experience within Reformed tertiary education, I'm not really aware of any widely used theological dictionaries. Instead people are much more likely to use and recommend systematic theology textbooks. Both still give definitions and explanations for theological concepts, the systematics books just organise them systematically rather than alphabetically. Potentially this also means that they can be a little more space efficient, as dictionaries would at times need to repeat information in different entries as each one needs to be largely stand alone, whereas a textbook can assume you've read the page before.
There are lots of systematic theology textbooks, but the ones I see recommended most would be those by Calvin, Michael Horton, R C Sproul, John Frame, Joel Beeke, and Wayne Grudem (though I wouldn't recommend him). Horton's is my usual go-to theology textbook. For more niche terms you may need to consult a more topic-specific text.

Because OP is looking for longer articles I was going to write an answer citing Encyclopedia of the Reformed Faith (1992) edited by Donald McKim.  Sample pages in the link.  I also found The Westminster Handbook to Reformed Theology (2001) by the same editor.

@GratefulDisciple I'm sure there are more actual Reformed dictionaries/encylopedias (like the one Mike suggested), but I've never really seen them recommended. Textbooks are where Reformed people generally go for theology terms. At least in my experience!

Yea good answer. I use TDNT a lot whenever I want a deep dive on a specific word in the bible. I like Hodge for systematic theology but you others lists are also good

Louis Berkof's "Systematic Theology" is the one I here most often mentioned, so a bit surprised it isn't mentioned above.  Any reason?  Another recommended by many teachers is Robert Reymond's "A New Systematic Theology of the Christian Faith", 1998, which I confess I like a lot because it grapples with issues, and takes a side: it isn't by any means "dry".  Recom. by John Frame and E Clowney, Westminster Theo. Sem, Escondido; J.I. Packer, Vancouver; Roger Nicole, Reformed Theo Sem, Maitland; Pastor R. Kent Hughes, College Church, Wheaton; Pastor P Masters, Metropolitan Tabernacle, London.

Berkhof is quite a bit of older than the ones I listed (other than Calvin of course). I haven't read him, but I think I remember people describing it as a harder read than more recent authors. I don't think I've heard of Reymond - there are a lot of systematics textbooks published in recent decades!

Well, I haven't read too much out of systematic theology books.. just a bit of Calvin's Institutes and Reymond.. so not much to compare with.  Berkof is still sitting on my shelf. Calvin I read to see how he, as a Presbyterian, handles the relationship similarity/difference the OT covenant and the NT covenant.  Was the OT covenant one of grace or works (primarily)?  Which leads to a warning maybe for the OP.. I don't know if any of the Systematic Theologies recommended are from a "Reformed Baptist" viewpoint.. maybe he doesn't want that.. but if he does, Do you know which are from a Baptist?

@AndrewShanks I think of those I listed only Grudem is a reformed baptist.

The Westminster Dictionary of Theological Terms is it good place to start. It covers more than 6,000 theological terms from a number of reformed Protestant theologies.
I'm not saying it's the only source necessary, but it's a good start for a good overview.

Thank you! Just yesterday I was skimming through it. I find the entries a bit brief; in the ones I saw, there were no patristic references, and some key authors were missing. To be honest, I’m not sure it convinced me too much.

@Ian The convincing has to come if what is being defined resonates with the scriptures.  You might try Systematic Theology by Wayne Grudem if the first recommendation was to simplified for you.

I'm browsing through it now and, while not a dictionary, it looks full of substance, thank you!

@Ian You can't expect a dictionary to provide a full justification from 2000 years of Christian history! Please edit the question if you want something more specific than simply a dictionary of theological terms.

@curiousdannii Of course not. But I know other dictionaries of theology and they are a bit more detailed than the one referenced above. I would contrast them for you but they are in Spanish and come from a Catholic background.
